# How to add a VBA macro which remove ALL the duplicates including the original based on a specific condition

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

i desperately need some help

i am new to macros and have been stuck on this one  : (  it is doing my head in...

i have an excel sheet with around  20,000 rows and 30 columns

below is a summary  I want to delete all members who have Ferrari’s   I  need the macro to  delete  all customers (rows) who have ferrari's  ..... however i need the macro to remove Row 2 as well because that same customer who has a ferrari, owns a bmw as well and perhaps other cars in the list

So the macro would delete  Row 1,2 and then row 4    (the trick is getting the macro to remove row #2 with row #1 because its the same customer who has a ferrari and another car hence i wont need to market anything to client A

```
  Customer   Car
```

1-    A               Ferrari   
2-    A             BMW  
3-    B             Mercedes  
4-    D             Ferrari  
5-    E              Nissan

Answer (score 0):

```
sub remover()
    for each veh in sheets("sheet1").range("B2:B999").cells
        if veh.value = "ferrari" or veh.value = "Ferrari" then
            customer = veh.offset(0, -1).value
            veh.entirerow.delete
            for each cust in sheets("sheet1").range("A2:A999").cells
                if cust.value = customer then
                    cust.entirerow.delete
                endif
            next
         end if
     next
End Sub
```

NOT TESTED - excuse any errors, its early in the morning, that should definitely give you some ideas for one way around your problem. If it doesn't work. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you ! i  just tried. it seem to work. i just need to rename the titles property as per the raw spreadsheet data.
what if as well it was several cars like Ferrari and Nissan and Porsche   should i just add them in the bracket next to ferrari ?

Comment: You would need to make small amendments to the `if` statement.
As per your example:
`if veh.value = "ferrari" or veh.value = "Nissan" or veh.value = "Porsche"`

Comment: So you mean it performs the "if" test on one spreadsheet, but removes the values from another?
To work in another workbook you do something a bit like this:
`workbooks("test.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`
Plus unless you were prepared to write another vba loop, you would have to be sure that the list orders were identical. This would be quite an "unsafe" medthod without any double-checking

Comment: @Bruno123 **Please don't forget to mark questions as answered**

Comment: HI RHYSOWEN ! i just re tested the  code it is actually not working correctly.  it does remove records off the raw list when i run it but it is keeping so many in the spreadsheet.    it is meant to remove all values of ferrari   and all the other rows associated with that customer based on the same ID .

Comment: it is definitely not working :  ( it does remove plenty of records but from the ones i specified  as values i saw plenty in the spreadsheet after i ran the macro  i dunno why.

Comment: am i supposed to be sorting in ascending or descending order by member before i do that  ?  or it does go and scan back and forth the whole  20,000 rows of the spreadsheet ?

Comment: Hi Bruno, I have no fixed this issue in the code. It should work now

Comment: @Bruno123 I have also made one or two amendments to make sure the code works okay

Comment: thank you ! it worked : ) can i get an extra code of line  to then filter and retain whatever remains based on another condition such as whoever has  a "mercedes" card for example? –

Comment: so for example, delete all customers who have a ferarri, unless they have a mercedes?

Comment: no  just as a step 2. just a simple filter from  retaining all the remaining records who have a Mercedes car afterwards from the remaining  data set.  : )      the logic behind it is to cross sell products for a specific niche  segment of consumers : )

Comment: @Bruno123 I know that overuse of the "comments" is frowned upon so we may need to move it out of here. But Am I right in saying you want to apply a filter to the remaining records to only show customers who have a Mercedes?

Comment: @rhys when deleting rows in a loop, you need to do this bottom up to avoid skipping rows.

Comment: hi brett/ i think you are right because rys/ i ran the macro and it still had  plenty of non filtered out rows . what change do we do to it to run it again? and yes you are right about me applying the filter after that. ...ok sorry didnt know that.. how do we move out of here ? could you inbox or email me ? –

Comment: I don't follow? I am using a for loop and my second loop goes back to cycle back through the customers?